# Sign convention for Bernoulli numbers

Tags: bernoulli-numbers

I can't seem to find an answer as to why there are two conventions for Bernoulli numbers. I have done a fair amount of research and can't find a definitive answer. Maybe I am just not reading between the lines but I would greatly appreciate any insight on the topic.

Comment: Because there are *two* definitions of the Bernoulli Numbers. Do you mean that there are two conventions for Bernoulli polynomials? i.e. $B_n(x)$ or $B_n^*(x)$.

Comment: Go here $\longrightarrow$ http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BernoulliNumber.html to know how to distinguish each of the definitions $B_n$ and $B_n^*$. I must say though, it ia weird because for polynomials, $B_n(x) = B_n^*(x)$.